# Django OAuth Authentication

Tags: reactjs, django, oauth-2.0, django-allauth, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I built an app (Django backend, React frontend) that whenever a client login it will generate JWT authentication. React will store the access token and client can use it to access Django backend database.
Then I want to add in social login feature (Google) so I will get back access token from that as well. However, this access token is different from the JWT access token generated before, so I wonder how can I integrate both ways of logging in a user smoothly on both Django and React?

For JWT I use djangorestframework-simplejwt
For social login I use django-allauth

I can run each individual way perfectly on React, but I don't know how to keep both the installations of JWT and allauth in Django settings.